# SSL Implementation in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

How to implement SSL and cdn SETup in magento

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you bought an SSL certificate?

If the site is not on local then please contact hosting team, they can help you better in this process.

Your settings looking fine to me.

Comment: we Bought ssl certificate from SSL.com. We install the ssl  certificate in Apache server.